# The OnPaintBackground method is never invoked for control derived from Button

Tags: c#, winforms, gradient

I've made a class `GradientButton` which suppose to be a Button which is filled with gradient background.

I draw gradient filling in the `OnPaintBackground()` method. Unfortunately it is never invoked, of course I added a `GradientButton` to a `Form` via toolbox:

```
  public class GradientButton : Button {

        public Color Color1 { get; set; }
        public Color Color2 { get; set; }

        public float Angle { get; set; }

        public GradientButton() {
            Color1 = Color.YellowGreen;
            Color2 = Color.LightGreen;
            Angle = 30;
        }



        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) {
            base.OnPaintBackground(e);
            Debug.WriteLine("This never prints");
            using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle,
                                                                       Color1,
                                                                       Color2,
                                                                       Angle)) {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
            }
        }
        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
            base.OnResize(e);
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

**Question:** How fill the button's background with the gradient? Why `OnPaintBackground` is not invoked? As far as I know it should be calledbefore  `OnPaint` method.

Comment: It is normally triggered by WM_ERASEBKGND but that message gets [special treatment](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Button.cs,db879261d0cac688) in Button.WndProc(), bypassing the normal handling.  The advantage is that no double-buffering is required.  It isn't needed, OnPaint() draws everything.  You in turn have to override OnPaint() instead.

Answer (score 5):

This is because the `Button` class has [ControlStyles.Opaque](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) flag set, which according to the documentation:

> If true, the control is drawn opaque and the background is not painted.

You can turn it off in your class constructor

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, false);
```

and your `OnPaintBackground` override will be invoked.

However, it would not help a lot - there is a reason the flag to be set to `true` - the `OnPaint` draws both background and face of the button, so whatever you do in `OnPaintBackground` will not have any affect of the button appearance. Unfortunately there is no option to paint just the background, so you need to override the `OnPaint` and actually draw **everything** yourself.

Comment: Checked it, understood, then I to created `UserControl` with a transparent button in it and drew `UserControl's` back color and I think it is the easiest solution, but is it right in your book?

Comment: Ha, my book says everything that works is right:) It might work, but additionally to setting button `BackColor` to `Color.Transparent` I think you'll need also to set `FlatStyle` to `Flat` and put some alpha in `FlatApprearance` `MouseDownBackColor` and `MouseOverBackColor`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the style of the form in the constructor ...

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
```

to ensure the OnPaint method is overridden. There are many settings for the [ControlStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can combine

Answer (score -2):

I would do this instead.

Firstly, change your constructor to this:

```
    public GradientButton()
   {
        Color1 = Color.YellowGreen;
        Color2 = Color.LightGreen;
        Angle = 30;
        Paint += new PaintEventHandler(GradientButton_Paint);
    }
```

And then add the below procedure:

```
    private void GradientButton_Paint(object sender,PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("This never prints");
        using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle,Color1,Color2,Angle))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
    }
```

I'm not entirely sure why your code doesn't work, but the way I've described always works for me. Hope that's good enough.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. There are two reasons why sb(not me) downvoted your answer. First one is that one suppose to override `OnPaint` method, not subscribe to the event. Second is that this causes to paint gradient over all contents of the button so the text is invisible.

Comment: Fair enough I suppose