# Unable to create a button gradient in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to add a gradient in c# by extending the System.Windows.Forms.button class. The problem I'm having is that it doesn't add the gradient to the button either in design or runtime, though the designer does pick up the color1, color2, and angle fields, so it's definitely overridden and instantiated correctly. Am I missing something ?

```
class ps_button : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    private Color _Color1 = Color.FromArgb(255, 224, 138, 25);
    private Color _Color2 = Color.FromArgb(255, 245, 202, 134);
    private float _ColorAngle = 45f;

    public Color Color1
    {
        get { return _Color1; }
        set
        {
            _Color1 = value;
            this.Invalidate(); // Tell the Form to repaint itself
        }
    }

    public Color Color2
    {
        get { return _Color2; }
        set
        {
            _Color2 = value;
            this.Invalidate(); // Tell the Form to repaint itself
        }
    }

    public float ColorAngle
    {
        get { return _ColorAngle; }
        set
        {
            _ColorAngle = value;
            this.Invalidate(); // Tell the Form to repaint itself
        }

    }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        // Getting the graphics object
        Graphics g = pevent.Graphics;

        // Creating the rectangle for the gradient
        Rectangle rBackground = new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                  this.Width, this.Height);

        // Creating the lineargradient
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush bBackground
            = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(rBackground,
                                              _Color1, _Color2, _ColorAngle);

        // Draw the gradient onto the form
        g.FillRectangle(bBackground, rBackground);

        // Disposing of the resources held by the brush
        bBackground.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you change the style property of the button?

Comment: Style? Do you maybe mean FlatStyle? That's set to standard.

Comment: C# does not have buttons. I've added the `winforms` tag since you indicate that with your inheritance.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't think to clarify; Probably why @DanielA.White asked about style.

Comment: _this.Invalidate(); // Tell the Form to repaint itself_ make that tell the __control__ to repaint etc etc etc Also: Check your params; if they are ok it ought to work.

Comment: @Taw Yes, I got the code from https://www.codeproject.com/articles/11417/gradient-forms-the-easy-way which was written for a form and I didn't think to change the comments.

Comment: I totally missed that you used the OnPaintBackground instead of the OnPaint event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `OnPaint()` function and use GDI+ to draw your gradient.

Something on the following lines:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
  base.OnPaint(pevent);

  pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(
    new PointF(0, this.Height / 2), new PointF(this.Width, this.Height / 2),
    Color.Red, Color.White), this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

This will draw a horizontal linear gradient (Red to White) from the left edge to the right edge of your button. Note that I have used constant colors in the above code. You should replace them with your properties. Similarly if you want to support gradient angle, use simple math to compute Start and End points of your gradient.

Comment: Okay but I overwrote OnPaintBackground. If I change that to onPaint, it does work, but paints over top of the text and border of the button.

Comment: You should call the base Paint after you drew the background then..

Comment: I don't know why you're getting downvoted, changing it from `OnPaintBackground` to `OnPaint` DOES draw the color. But then it covers up the border/text. Calling onPaint after doesn't seem to solve that.

Comment: Ah I see, paint doesn't draw the text unless I tell it to.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793877/the-onpaintbackground-method-is-never-invoked-for-control-derived-from-button) for a discussion on why OnPaintBackground() doesn't work.