# c# button color has a two tone effect, how can I set this in code?

Tags: c#, button, gradient

When I change the color on my button it looses the two tone effect. The closest I can come to understating this is a gradient fill but I'm thinking it must be easier then that? All default buttons have this light/dark fill but when I set the color its flat. I'm not able to find any reference (other then gradient fill) of this on the net.

Comment: Using wpf or winforms?

Comment: @sean green  If it is WinForms, look at this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793877/the-onpaintbackground-method-is-never-invoked-for-control-derived-from-button) and read ALL the comments.

Comment: I'll look but I honestly do not know what c# uses.

Comment: hmm, I know what that link is saying but I don't see how it applies. Also my issues is not that the gradient is not working. I have not tried that yet. The effect I see does not look like a gradient as it only has 2 colors. Maybe that is the answer to my question... I just need to paint a gradient. I woudl figure the default button form the IDE can be reproduced easily.

Comment: Looks like it is winforms

Comment: I finally found my issue talked about 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569200/how-to-reset-to-default-button-backcolor